# How to call the currently running method/class in python

Tags: python, class

Hi I am trying to call the currently running self.x.run(). This code has been arranged and it cannot be changed the ordering

```
class SocketWatcher(Thread):
   .....
   def checker(self):
      # here I want to call the currently running self.x.run() that has been
      # created in the mainPlayer class..

class counterTicket(Thread):
   ....
   def increment(self):

class mainPlayer:
   ....
   def run(self, obj):
     self.x = counterTicket()
     self.x.increment()
```

is it possible?

I just want to call a running method that has been called at the mainPlayer class. but I dont have any idea on how to do it. If im going to instantiate the counterTicket class to call the increment() at the SocketWatcher class, it seems it will create new counterTicket class and not the counterTicket class that has been currently running by the mainPlayer class

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? It's not obvious what you are expecting.

Comment: Have you tried the (obvious) solution of setting a global variable equal to `self` or `self.x` in the beginning of your `def run` and then setting that variable to `None` just before the function returns? I'm fairly certain you'll be able to just pull the reference of the currently running method/class instance that way with your other threads.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what you are doing...

Maybe:

```
class mainPlayer(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ticket = counterTicket()
    def run(self):
        self.ticket.increment()
class SocketWatcher(Thread):
    def checker(self, player):
        player.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

make run() a class method:

```
class mainPlayer(object):
    # whatever methods predefined

    @classmethod
    def run(cls, obj):
        if not isinstance(cls, obj):
            raise TypeError("input type error")
        input.x = counterTicket()
        input.x.increment()
```

Then you can call it within instances:

```
 # a method in class definition
 def foo(self, input):
     mainPlayer.run(input)
```